# MacOS X Server Lion with multi-domain mailserver?

Tags: email-server, mac-osx-server, lion

Is a Mac OS X Lion Server capable of servicing multiple e-mail domains? We want to get a Mac to use as a standalone mailserver, but the Apple web site doesn't appear to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It surely can be done: Mac OS X Server uses [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org) [Dovecot](http://dovecot.org/) to provide e-mail services.

If Apple's documentation does not provide a clear answer as to how you can configure e-mail domains, the documentation for the underlying open-source e-mail services surely will.